# Is there a better method instead of 2 nested subqueries for this task?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am trying to write the SQL to generate the count of unique users who have purchased product B but have never purchased product C.

| user_id | product | date_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | B | 2014-11-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | C | 2015-05-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | A | 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | C | 2014-12-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | B | 2015-02-15 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | D | 2014-09-23 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | E | 2014-06-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | E | 2014-12-14 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | F | 2015-03-03 00:00:00.000 |

I have a solution but its so ugly I bet there is a better way of doing it. Any thoughts on how to make this better in terms of best practices?

```
SELECT Count(*) AS bought_b_no_c
FROM   (SELECT user_id,
               Sum(bought_b_no_c) AS boolean_b_no_c
        FROM   (SELECT user_id,
                       product,
                       CASE
                         WHEN product = 'B' THEN 1
                         WHEN product = 'C' THEN -1
                         ELSE 0
                       END AS bought_b_no_c
                FROM   table_purchases) AS T
        GROUP  BY user_id) AS J
WHERE  boolean_b_no_c = 1
```

I am editing since there seem to be few answers that have operations such as SUM(product = 'C')  but this returns an error such as:   Incorrect syntax near ')' and it highlights the closing parathesis around the SUM function next to C.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all the users who bought 'B' but not 'C' with this query:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table_purchases
WHERE product IN ('B', 'C')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(product = 'C') = 0;
```

Then you only need to count its results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS bought_b_no_c
FROM (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM table_purchases
  WHERE product IN ('B', 'C')
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING SUM(product = 'C') = 0
) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple aggregation will do here:

```sql
SELECT user_id
FROM table_purchases
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(product = 'B') > 0 AND SUM(product = 'C') = 0;
```

We could also phrase this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM table_purchases t1
WHERE product = 'B' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_purchases t2
                  WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND
                        t2.product = 'C');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am writing this on my mobile phone so lacking a detailed explanation.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.user_id) AS bought_b_no_c
FROM table_purchases t1
LEFT JOIN table_purchases t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t2.product = 'C'
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL AND t1.product = 'B';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c55f3f/1)